# How to set up 2 textviews and an icon?

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

I can't get the correct view that I am trying to do. I want to set an icon on the left and 2 textviews near by on the right.
My problem is that I can't see the second textview and the first seems to be too big.

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="50dip"
      android:layout_height="50dip"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:src="@drawable/rss" />
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/linear"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical">
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:textSize="20dip" />
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pubdate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:textSize="10dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check the solution I have posted. That will solve your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your XML with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="50dip"
      android:layout_height="50dip"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:src="@drawable/rss" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="20dip" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/pubdate"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: It's because you are setting the textviews to fill the width of the parent(which is second linear layout). But they need to be wrapped with content. If you still want them to occupy equal space in width wise, you can keep weights to the textviews again in the second linear layout as I did it in first linear layout and it's children.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="30" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="10" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text = "textview1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:textSize="20dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pubdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text = "textview2blahblahblahblahblah"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
       />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the TextViews change the width to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` of both.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pubdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="20dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you want to set the both textview in horizontal then set the Linear Layout orientation is horizontal and in case of vertical set orientation vertical like this  android:orientation="vertical"

Answer (score -1):

Use This XML Instead of above code This Is Perfect for you.

I also use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLa"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/accident" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `LinearLayout` inside other `LinearLayout`? Why not add 5 more layers of layouts?